# Gradle - Protobuf module is rebuilt almost every time

Tags: gradle, protobuf-java

I have a Gradle build with a module generating grpc code. The `gradle.build.kts` uses version 0.9.1 of the protobuf plugin and the file looks like this:

```kotlin
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:$protobufVersion"
    }
    plugins {
        id("grpc") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:$grpcVersion"
        }
        id("grpckt") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:$grpcKotlinVersion:jdk8@jar"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        ofSourceSet("main").forEach { task ->
            task.plugins {
                id("grpc")
                id("grpckt")
            }
            task.builtins {
                id("kotlin")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code generation works well enough, but there is something causing Gradle to re-build that module even though nothing has changed causing the build to be a lot slower then it has to. Running the build with `--scan` I found this:

```
The task was not up-to-date because of the following reasons:   
Output property 'destDir' file xxx/build/extracted-protos/main has been removed.
```

Seems like the build is "fighting" over that folder. Is there something wrong with my build configuration?

Comment: It's possible that the Profobuf plugin just isn't compatible with Gradle task avoidance. What is the FQN of the class task that you want to be up to date? What is the other task that is removing `build/extracted-protos/main`?

Comment: I have another module generating plain protobuf (no grpc) and that is not rebuilt each time so I think it has something to do with the grpc part of my configuration. How can I tell what is removing `build/extracted-protos/main`?